# Ransomware with .adobe extension

Tags: windows, decryption, ransomware

It is possible to decrypt file with .adobe extension ?

File after encryption look like this : `filename.id-5735353.[email@example.com].adobe`  .

I did a little research and found information about ".adobe". File has been encrypted by ransomware form **Dharma** family. At any site unfortunately peoples say it isn't able to decrypt. Can You confirm this information ? Maybe some of You have idea how to recover data.

I don't have file backup so i cannot recover previous data.

Comment: Kaspersky maintains a list of possible ransomware decryptors. Here's the results for Dharma https://noransom.kaspersky.com/?tool=Dharma looks like there's 1 match.

Comment: Thanks. I will check it and return with result. But i didn't see .adobe extension there.

Comment: search for "Dharma".

Comment: Unfortunately tool from kaspersky doesn't work. Doesn't support .adobe file.